# Overlapping the Excel Application By Recently Opened Application - C#

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, excel-addins, vba

In my VSTO Excel AddIn Application Facing an issue with window overlapping by recently opened window at the time of displaying alert box.

In below screen shot if I click on OK button Excel application is minimized and some other (Recently Opened) window is opened.

But I still want to be in parameters window, just want to close alert box only.

[image]

Comment: Yes, what do you intend to do? [ask]

Comment: I still want to be in parameters window, just want to close alert box only.